# Drupal: send node content in email after submit

Tags: php, drupal

I have a content type that the content needs to be emailed righted after submitting, is it any simple way to do that with drupal? I have rules mod but not seeing a way to actually send the content... just an email reminder at most.

Comment: In Rules, there is an action named "send an email to an arbitrary email address", and you can use tokens there (make sure that you have enabled token module).
If you want to send the email to author himself, you can use the "send an email" action as well.

Answer (score 0):

First try Ayesh's suggestion in the comment box. Its simple enough and if your requirement is not full filled then do the below.

1) set up rules to trigger when a content has been saved as per your criteria.
2) Rules has a hook called hook_rules_action_info() you need to make a file called YOURMODULE.rules.inc in your module dir and use this hook there.
3) There you can then send the email as per your specific need. using the drupal_mail function()

Hope this helps. 
Vishal

Comment: If you're going to go through the trouble of writing a module, wouldn't it be cleaner to just use hook_node_insert (http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) hook to accomplish this?

Comment: @KerrM : I think your method would be a better option